# How to emit file with asset modules at the end of a loader chain?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm learning about webpack loaders.

I wanted to build a chain of loaders for markdown files.

I had this rule in `webpack.config.js`

```js
            {
                test: /\.md$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "markdown-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

This allows me to do

```js
import source from './markdown/example.md';
console.log(source);
```

but I would prefer to have the markdown to be emitted as a file asset. I would reach for [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to do the job, but it's marked as deprecated. I haven't found out how to add an [asset module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) to the loader chain.

What would now be the correct way to emit a file at the end of a loader chain? From the beginner's perspective, this seems like basic functionality, so I'm not sure if reaching for special loaders like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emit-file-loader) should be necessary.

I tried adding `type: asset/resource` right after `use:[]` and a markdown file with gibberish name was produced with this content verbatim:

```
// Module
var code = "<h1 id=\"yaaay\">Yaaay!</h1> <p>Now I can work with markdown again!</p> <ul> <li>Something here</li> <li>something there</li> </ul> ";
// Exports
export default code;
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I barely remember what I was trying to achieve with this. It you find out, share your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know is a long time without response. But i found if you add `type: 'asset/resource'` after `test` do the work:

```
{
    test: /\.md$/,
    type: 'asset/resource', // <-- add here 
    use: [
        {
            loader: "html-loader"
        },
        {
            loader: "markdown-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```