# Migrate rule containing multiple loaders from Webpack v4 to v5

Tags: webpack

I want to migrate this current rule from Webpack v4 to v5:

```
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.twig$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            context: './src',
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          },
        },
        {loader: 'extract-loader'},
        {loader: 'html-loader'},
      ],
    },

    ...
```

The thing is that file-loader will be deprecated.

Source: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#clean-up-configuration

> If you have rules defined for loading assets using raw-loader, url-loader, or file-loader, please use Asset Modules instead as they're going to be deprecated in near future.

But this rule contains multiple loaders, and I don't know how to reorganize the code to use

```
type: 'asset/resource',
```

Without breaking the chain of execution.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [How to emit file with asset modules at the end of a loader chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573516/how-to-emit-file-with-asset-modules-at-the-end-of-a-loader-chain/73579220#73579220)

If you add `type: 'asset/resource'` after `test` do the work:

```
rules: [
{
  test: /\.twig$/,
  type: 'asset/resource', // <-- here
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        context: './src',
        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
      },
    },
    {loader: 'extract-loader'},
    {loader: 'html-loader'},
  ],
},
```